# Quartz scheduler start and end time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have started using quartz scheduler in my application.I want to know whether we can find the actual start time of a scheduler and the actual time at which the scheduler ends.

Comment: Well, you specify the start time of the scheduler and the end time is when it finishes its job! What do you mean by find out? Do you want to get the scheduled start time while the application is running? Could you be more specific please?

Comment: yes i need to know the actual scheduled start time and also when the scheduler completes its job i need to know that time time when scheduleer finished

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [JobListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobListener.html) for that.

The method jobToBeExecuted runs before the job starts and jobWasExecuted after it ends.

EDIT:

To further expand on the issue:

1. You can use the [JobDetail](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobDetail.html) object to store data about the job (look at [getJobDataMap](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobDetail.html#getJobDataMap%28%29)).
2. jobToBeExecuted method is called **automatically** each time the job is about to execute and it accepts a [JobExecutionContext](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html) which has a method [getJobDetails](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html#getJobDetail%28%29) (look at section 1)
3. Same goes for jobWasExecuted, only this one is called after the job finished.

Look [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/) for further information.

Comment: could u please explain me exactly how? actualy I not getting anything on web

Comment: yes i got it but i need an example or a small demo to understand it completely